# boost::program_options parse command line always with empty value

Tags: c++, boost

On debian stretch, and `gcc 6.4.0`, `boost 1.66.0`

`boost::program_options` parse command line always with empty value.
The code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    using namespace boost::program_options;
    options_description desc{"Options"};
    desc.add_options()
            ("help,h", "Help screen")
            ("target,t", value<std::string>()->required(), "Set the target.");
    command_line_parser parser{argc, argv};
    parser.options(desc).allow_unregistered().style(command_line_style::default_style | command_line_style::allow_slash_for_short);
    parsed_options parsed_options = parser.run();
    variables_map vm;
    store(parsed_options, vm);
    notify(vm);
    if (vm.count("help"))
    {
        std::cout << desc << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    if (vm["target"].empty())
    {
        std::cout << "Error: empty" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    if (vm.count("target"))
    {
        std::string target = vm["target"].as<std::string>();
        std::cout << target << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and then, compile and run.

```
./foo --target start
```

and the `vm["target"].empty()` is alway `TRUE`. Why ??

Comment: It works fine on my ubuntu, g++ 5.4, boost 1.58

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess that you're running the wrong binary.

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f4c2a23e2ee69565)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    using namespace boost::program_options;
    options_description desc{"Options"};
    desc.add_options()
            ("help,h", "Help screen")
            ("target,t", value<std::string>()->required(), "Set the target.");

    command_line_parser parser{argc, argv};
    parser.options(desc).allow_unregistered().style(command_line_style::default_style | command_line_style::allow_slash_for_short);
    parsed_options parsed_options = parser.run();
    variables_map vm;
    store(parsed_options, vm);
    notify(vm);

    if (vm.count("help"))
    {
        std::cout << desc << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    if (vm["target"].empty())
    {
        std::cout << "Error: empty" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    if (vm.count("target"))
    {
        std::string target = vm["target"].as<std::string>();
        std::cout << target << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Prints for `./a.out --target HELLOWORLD`:

```
HELLOWORLD
```